# How can I test a React component that relies on Redux Toolkit useSelectors?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to write tests for my React component that works with Redux Toolkit. I'm currently getting an error that states

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
      666 |       const fraudValuesByCategory = stateReport.fraud_types
    > 667 |         .map(fraudTypeId => fraudCategoryDescById[fraudTypeId])
          |          ^
      668 |         .reduce((aggregator, {description, category}) => {
      669 |           const x = { [category]: [description].concat(aggregator[category] || []) };
      670 |           return ({
```

I've mocked the store and render it like so in my describe function

```
const props = {
  index: 0,
  // setActiveTab={ i => setActiveTab(i)}
  entityToken: 'abc1234',
  entity: '',
  featureFlags,
  domainToken,
  customerAgentId: 1,
  caseToken: 'C-M7EOZfrdCBjEMnO3p9JQ"',
};

const initialState = {
    report: {
      fraud_types: [2, 4, 7, 15, 19, 22, 43],
    },
    wizard: {},
    prefill: {},
    status: true,
    error: false,
    isDraft: null,
    fraudTypes: {
      ACH: {
        fraud_category: 'fraud',
        fraud_subcategory: 'a',
        fraud_type_id: '7',
      },
      'Account takeover': {
        fraud_category: 'misc',
        fraud_subcategory: 'a',
        fraud_type_id: '43',
      },
    },
    suspiciousActivity: null,
  };
  const mockStore = configureStore();
  const store = mockStore(initialState);

  const spy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useSelector');
  spy.mockReturnValue({ username: 'test' });


  const setup = (prop: typeof props) => {
    render(<Provider store={store}><FormGroup {...prop} /></Provider>);
  };

test('IP Address should be at index 29', () => {
    props.index = 1;
    setup(props);
    expect(FORM_CONTROLS.steps[props.index].controls[29].label).toEqual('43. IP Address (enter the IP address/date/timestamp of the subject\'s electronic internet based contact with the financial institution, if known)');
  });
```

My impression is that I haven't mocked the store correctly and so when it tries to map stateReport.fraud_types it's not able to? What am I doing wrong?